# Do form validation that does not use database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form and I have made some inputs required. After submitting the form that value will be sent to an API. I know that the validations are put into model file but since I do not have a database, how can I use the rails validation?

Right now I am validating the code inside a controller using `if else`.

```
if !params[:groups][:name].blank? && !params[:groups][:make].blank? && !params[:groups][:model].blank? && !params[:groups][:firmware].blank?
```

This does the work but it is not very elegant.

Comment: Are you using rails 4?

Comment: yes, I am using rails 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html), it lets you do "model things" without the database. There were some limitations that made me not use it in the end (I think related to associations) but for simple stuff it's great (and it's a part of how ActiveRecord works.

Example code from docs

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :age
  validates :name, :age, presence: true
end
```

Comment: what if the value if coming from a url? I am trying it in the same way as above and in my controller I have

 `g = Person.new

ap  g.error
`
I got an empty hash.

Comment: The value from url is like `params[:gs_data_source][:name]`

Comment: `Person.new(params[:gs_data_source])`

Answer (score 1):

this is easy. On the form input fields that you NEED, add `required: true` For example:

```
<%= form.for @something do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title', required: true %>
<% end %>
```

The user gets an error if the required fields are not filled out correctlty.

Is this what you mean?

Justin

**EDIT**

I guess I would look at using the gem 
[client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)

Let us know how you go

Comment: yes I know about that. I am trying to do server side validation.

Comment: that is a great gem. I will take a look at it.